# SQL C# INSERT query sent doesn't actually add any new entries to the table

Tags: c#, sql

I'm currently using C# to try and execute queries on a SQL database. The SELECT query works fine but the INSERT one doesn't.

I've launched the same query from SQL Server manager itself and it works fine but when I send it from the C# (using an ASP page with text boxes to specify the values being sent for the columns) the page simply refreshes and doesn't show any errors.

The fact that the SELECT query works tells me that server connects fine and that it isn't the problem. I've used breakpoints in the C# code to check if the variables send correctly from the text boxes and they are they should be.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Here's the Code:

```
  protected void SendMyData_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //(NO RECORD SET IS NEEDED IN THIS FUNCTION SEEING AS HOW WE'RE NOT FETCHING ANYTHING) 

         SqlConnection conServer = new SqlConnection(CDatabase.ConnectionString());

        // Database variables
        string Track_Name   = TextBox8.Text;

        string Track_No     = TextBox10.Text;
        long TN             = Convert.ToInt64(Track_No);

        string Artist_ID    = TextBox11.Text;
        long ArtID          = Convert.ToInt64(Artist_ID);

        string Album_ID     = TextBox12.Text;
        long AlbID          = Convert.ToInt64(Album_ID);
        //SUB THESE INTO THE SQL QUERY 

        try
        {
            string qrySQL = string.Format("INSERT INTO Tracks ([Track_Name],[Track_No],[Artist_ID],[Album_ID]) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3})", Track_Name, TN, ArtID, AlbID);

            //This is the string Used to send (Note the NonReturn(As we aren't fetching anything) : " conServer.Open();CDatabase.ExecuteNonReturnQuery(qrySQL);"

            conServer.Open();
            //(NO RECORD SET IS NEEDED IN THIS FUNCTION SEEING AS HOW WE'RE NOT FETCHING ANYTHING) 
            CDatabase.ExecuteNonReturnQuery(qrySQL);
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        finally
        {
           conServer.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Is this a coursework? It definitely looks like it :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there are *at least two* things seriously wrong here:

- You're embedding values directly in your SQL. Welcome to SQL Injection Attack Land. *Don't do that.* Use parameterized SQL instead, specifying the values separately. (See the docs for [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for an example.)
- You're catching all exceptions and just swallowing them, with no logging. It's entirely possible that this code is throwing an exception which explains *exactly* what's going wrong - but you'd never know, because your code has its metaphorical fingers in its ears.

My guess is that it *is* throwing an exception due to the track name neither being parameterized nor quoted - you've got an arbitrary string in the middle of your SQL.

Catching all exceptions is almost always wrong, and particularly at this level. Usually you should let exceptions propagate up to higher levels, where you may well have a top-level catch-all block for "something went wrong with the request and we don't want to bring down the whole server" - ASP.NET supplies one of these for you, of course, and allows you to specify how errors should be handled.

Additionally, rather than explicitly closing the SQL connection, I would wrap the whole thing in a `using` statement (and only after parsing the input, too).

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = ...)
    {
        // Execute the command
    }
}
```

Finally, your variable naming is inconsistent - sometimes you're using `camelCase` and sometimes you're using `PascalCase`. It's unusual to see Pascal cased variables, to be honest - likewise variables with underscores in. Abbreviating "Artist" and "Album" to "Art" and "Alb" just makes the code less readable too.

Comment: Thanks. I got rid of the empty catch and created a trace file and am now getting this error in there: 
"26/10/2011 10:01:22: Exception adding account. The name "track1" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
"

I'm guessing this has something to do with the non-quoted track name?

Comment: @Adam: Yes. But don't fix it by adding quotes to your format string - fix it by using a parameterized SQL statement.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH ! I added '' around the {0} as it's a characters that we're sending not a string.I'm now working on getting it into parametrized SQL.

If anyone was wondering I'm doing this to learn C# -> SQL stuff which I will later use for an extended project. (I'm a year 13 UK student by the way - Senior in High school to you Americans)

Comment: You are injecting values because you create your string dynamic by using string.Format(..., arg1, ...);. What if arg1 would contain a sql statement itself? Then someone would have injected sql into your query and it will be executed

Comment: @Adam: Consider what happens if someone types a track name of `IGNORE', 0, 0, 0); DROP TABLE Tracks; //`. What would your SQL statement look like at that point, and do you *really* want to execute it? To put it another way, you're doing the SQL equivalent of letting people write C# code to be executed directly on your web server. Not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks all. I'm off to parametrize it all.

Comment: @Adam: Goodo - it's good to get into the habit nice and early :) See http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

The page will refresh because you have an empty catch clause. So if there is an error you will catch it and swallow the error.

Try removing the catch clause or adding a new 'throw' in it which will retrow the exception

Answer (score 0):

Your code is throing an exception that you are not seeing because of the empty catch. Your text values have no ' around them which makes the SQL fail. AS mentioned by others you should used parameterized SQL which would not only fix this problem but also keep you safe(r) from SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 0):

Following will work:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
string qrySQL = string.Format("INSERT INTO Tracks ([Track_Name],[Track_No],[Artist_ID],[Album_ID]) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3})", Track_Name, TN, ArtID, AlbID);
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(qrySQL, sqlConnection);
sqlConnection.Open();
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You would be better of using parameters to avoid problems with Data Types and Security issues.

```
string qrySQL = "INSERT INTO Tracks ([Track_Name],[Track_No],[Artist_ID],[Album_ID]) VALUES (@Track_Name,@Track_No,@Artist_ID,@Album_ID)";
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Track_Name", "Value");
```

and so on..

Comment: I don't think it will work because the query will fail - the value for Track_Name needs to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a coursework? It definitely looks like it :P

Also, are the square brackets around the parameters an SQL Server thing? Ive not seen it written like that before. I would have thought it was just "INSERT INTO Tracks (Track_Name, Track_Number, etc...
Try printing out the exception... such as

```
catch Exception e{
print e
}
```

So you can see whats happening

Not sure on the exact syntax

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't the first value (Track_Name) be quoted, since it's a string?

```
string qrySQL = string.Format("INSERT INTO Tracks ([Track_Name],[Track_No],[Artist_ID],[Album_ID]) VALUES ('{0}', {1}, {2}, {3})", Track_Name, TN, ArtID, AlbID);
```

**EDITED TO ADD**

As others have said (in their better and more complete answers, IMO), you're wide open to SQL Injection attacks with the code as is - the only thing my answer did was fix the query so it would actually insert.

Of course, as Jon Skeet pointed out, you need to be doing parmaterized SQL.  I appreciate the accepted answer, but I Jon's was the better overall answer, and you should really accept that one - other users may come across this question in their own searches, and should have the most accurate and complete answer (IMO).

Comment: and clearly we also want to set the value of `TextBox8.Text` to `',0,0,0);TRUNCATE TABLE Tracks;DROP TABLE Tracks;SELECT 1 WHERE 1 IN ('0`

Comment: Others had addressed the SQL Injection risk, and I felt they had better overall answers (like Jon Skeet).  I probably should have come back and updated my answer to make it more complete.

Comment: Wow...a -1 on an old answer where I even edited it to point out that Jon Skeet's was the correct answer.  Whatever.